# Решил запарсит вот ошибка

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

File "pars.py", line 11
    div = soup.find('div', class_ = 'row click_container-link', class_ = 'set_href')
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

Вот код:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html( url ):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse( html ):
    soup = BeautifulSoup( html )
    div = soup.find('div', class_ = 'row click_container-link', class_ = 'set_href')
    print(div.prettify())
def main():
    parse(get_html('https://www.weblancer.net/'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Два раза указываете параметр `class_`. Передавайте список. И лучше через словарь.

***Пример:***

```py
div = soup.find('div', {'class': ['row', 'click_container-link', 'set_href']})
```